# How can I enable iis 5.1 compression on windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, iis, compression

Is there any other way to enable compression in IIS5.1 other than using the command line?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742379.aspx

These instructions reference a Services tab that I do not have.  There are some command line instructions, but I wanted to see if that was the only way.

++bonus points
If I must use the command line to add compression, will the same script run on IIS6.0?  That is what our site is using to be hosted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> HTTP Compression can only be enabled
>   for IIS on a Windows server. The
>   option for it is not present for the
>   IIS server running on Windows XP.

Source: http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/windows/howto_iis_http_compression.htm